# How to split a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In python, I can remove the first item from array `xs` like so:

```
xs = xs[1:]
```

How could I do that with the following javascript array?

```
var data = {{data}}
```

Comment: 1. That's not an Array. 2. jQuery doesn't have arrays, **JavaScript** has arrays. 3. Have you done any research? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the first value out of an array *and* remove it from the array, you can use `Array#shift` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) | [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.shift)):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];   // An array
var first = a.shift();  // Remove and return the first entry
console.log(first);     // Show the value we got
console.log(a);         // Show the updated state of the array
```

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `splice` function, not an specific of jQuery.

```js
var fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Kiwi"];
var removed = fruit.splice(0, 1);
console.log(removed);
console.log(fruit);
```

The result is `["Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Kiwi"]`

Comment: Indeed, this is the other way. `shift` returns the value directly, `splice` will return an array of the values removed. So both do the job, the one you pick depends on what you want to do with the result.

Comment: `splice` would be preferred if we were removing more than 1 from the start. It's also similar to the Python version. In this case `shift` is simpler though.

Comment: @4castle Indeed it would in that case.